# What is <meta http-equiv="Reply-to" content="admin@example.com" />?

Tags: html, http-headers

What does the following HTML code do?

```
<meta http-equiv="Reply-to" content="admin@example.com" />
```

There does not seem to a "Reply-to" equivalent header in HTTP. Should I remove it or correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure 'Reply-to' is still valid. It's not listed in the [Sitepoint Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/meta/http-equiv). However, there is an [ancient W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html) that says:

> HTTP servers may read the content of the document HEAD to generate header fields corresponding to any elements defining a value for the attribute HTTP-EQUIV. (14)
>
> […]
>
> If the document contains:
>
> `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Tue, 04 Dec 1993 21:29:02 GMT">`
>   `<meta http-equiv="Keywords" CONTENT="Fred">`
>   `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Reply-to" content="fielding@ics.uci.edu (Roy Fielding)">`
>   `<Meta Http-equiv="Keywords"` CONTENT="Barney">`
>
> then the server may include the
>   following header fields:
>
> Expires: Tue, 04 Dec 1993 21:29:02 GMT
>   Keywords: Fred, Barney
>   Reply-to: fielding@ics.uci.edu (Roy Fielding)

Comment: Wow that is from the HTML 2.0 spec, 1995.

Comment: @Liam yeah. that's why I said ancient :) came up as one of the first serps in google though.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably supposed to use the `name` attribute instead of `http-equiv`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Reply-to" content="admin@example.com" />
```

The 'reply-to' option was intended to be a way of publishing your email address, back when there was no spam problem. Using it now will more than likely only result in spam email.

Answer (score 0):

Reply-to is the value that goes in the name attribute. You do not want to give them your e-mail address. You want to collect there e-mail address so use mailto: in the a element within the web page. when they e-mail you, you got there name and e-mail address. For more information go to

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_meta_name.asp?output=print)